# Override Fragment functions on Xamarin Android if fragment is created using Forms Embedding

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I have created a forms page in Xamarin and used that page as a fragment using Xamarin Forms Embedding.

```
var fragment = new FormsPage().CreateFragment(context);
```

I would like to override the OnBackPressed() control in Android version of the app.
What's the best possible way to do it as I can't override it inside the Xamarin Forms Page.

Comment: Why did you override the `OnBackPressed()` method ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I would like to override the OnBackPressed() control in Android version of the app.

You could override [OnBackButtonPressed](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/Xamarin.Forms.NavigationPage.OnBackButtonPressed()/) in Xamarin.Forms, this event also be raised when the hardware back button is pressed in `Android` and this event is not raised on `iOS`.

If you want remove fragment from the stack in `OnBackPressed()` method, you could override this method in your `Activity` like this :

```
public override void OnBackPressed()
{
    base.OnBackPressed();
    if (FragmentManager.BackStackEntryCount != 0)
    {
        FragmentManager.PopBackStack();
    }
    else
    {
        base.OnBackPressed();
    }
}
```

Comment: Shen . Hi York, This solution works. But I noticed that our complete app uses the Support Fragment Manager for managing the fragments.

As of now, I cannot convert a forms page into support fragment. That's why the back stack causes some trouble like it does not show the back button on top.